# Tool that suggests tactics exercises based on game analysis

Tags: analysis, engines, software, tactics, training

Does anyone know of any common tool that can go throughout your game database (I have a couple of hundreds of my game's PGNs), and extract tactics that one should be training? I believe something as suggesting board positions related to blunders, missed mates in 1, 2, 3, missed forks, etc.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Both ChessBase and Fritz do this. I am not sure if others do it too, but this is a great feature of many products from Chessbase.

If you can pick up Chessbase, well and good. Otherwise look into Fritz that might be one version behind the latest version. They sometimes go on sale on Amazon.com and elsewhere.

Here's what you do:

1. You ask Fritz (or similar engine) to analyze your games.
2. Select the option that asks if it should create exercises during full analysis.
3. Once it completes the analysis (it can analyze all 200 of your games if you give it enough time), you can then play through the tactics from your own games.

ProTip: Players will sometimes subset only those games that have exercises, move it to a new database, and play through these exercises. You are essentially training on situations that occur in your own games, a great way to improve.

Hope that helps.